# How to add a timestamp to the filename when unloading from Snowflake to AZ blob?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, file-format

I have created a file format in Snowflake of CSV type for data unloading; and want the filename to be appended with current timestamp .

```
create or replace file format "DEV_DB"."SCHEMA".my_out_file              
   -- type = csv
      compression = none
      FILE_EXTENSION = 'txt' 

copy into devstg/A/OutputFiles/my_outbound
     from (select * from "DEV_DB"."SCHEMA"."TABLE")
     file_format = my_out_file
     OVERWRITE=TRUE
     SINGLE=TRUE;
```

This is creating an output file with filename : my_outbound.
The desired filename is my_outbound_05132022171500

How to append the timestamp to a filename in Snowflake/Azure?

Thanks

Comment: I tried the below code and it did not help - 
DECLARE
   query STRING;
   date_str STRING;
BEGIN 
    SELECT TO_CHAR(current_date,'mmddyyyy') INTO :date_str;
    QUERY := 'copy into @my_stage/my_file_' || date_str || '.csv table($my_table) 
    file_format=(type=csv compression=none skip_header=1
        field_optionally_enclosed_by= \'"\')
        header = true
        single = true
        max_file_size = 4900000000;';
                 
   --EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :QUERY;
   
   RETURN :QUERY;
END;

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try. Your SQL Stored Proc was really close but had a few minor bugs when assigning the variable to the date_str.  Note you can't re-run it on the same day without use over the OVERWRITE param (or adding a second timestamp to the date). Also note that the stage name & table name need to be modified.

Hope this helps.

If using SnowSight use this block:

```
DECLARE 
  query STRING; 
  date_str STRING; 
  table_nm STRING :='TEMP2';
  BEGIN 
  
  date_str :=  TO_CHAR(current_date(),'mmddyyyy');
  QUERY := 'copy into @pn_stage/my_file_' || date_str || '.csv 
  FROM (SELECT * FROM ' || :table_nm ||') 
     file_format=(type=csv 
     compression=none 
     skip_header=1 field_optionally_enclosed_by= \'"\') 
     header = true 
     single = true 
     max_file_size = 4900000000;';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (:QUERY); 
  RETURN QUERY; 
END;
```

Same code for the Classic UI:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
$$
DECLARE 
  query STRING; 
  date_str STRING; 
  table_nm STRING :='TEMP2';
  BEGIN 
  
  date_str :=  TO_CHAR(current_date(),'mmddyyyy');
  QUERY := 'copy into @pn_stage/my_file_' || date_str || '.csv 
  FROM (SELECT * FROM ' || :table_nm ||') 
     file_format=(type=csv 
     compression=none 
     skip_header=1 field_optionally_enclosed_by= \'"\') 
     header = true 
     single = true 
     max_file_size = 4900000000';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (:QUERY); 
  RETURN QUERY; 
END; 
$$;
```

Comment: Hello Needleman, Thank you for the code but it does not work in snowflake web ui. Is there a way to create a function?

Comment: Are you in classic ui or snowsight? I can update for both.

Comment: @SmitaMaskar please try the other block formatted for the classic UI. More info on the difference with SnowScripting here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/running-examples.html#introduction. Also, please make sure to check your stage and table names

Answer (score 0):

This should also work, if you are not averse to declaring variable every time.
Change variable declaration as per parameters that needs to be included.

```
set var='copy into @test_stage/fileprefix_'||to_char(current_timestamp(),'yyyymmddhh24miss')||' from yourtable';


execute immediate $var;
```